# QTableView Vertical header

Tags: pyqt6

PyQt6:
On Win10 Vertical header has only line numbers no lines.
On Linux KDE has both.

Did I miss something or bug?
I'm not able to test on MAC.

[image: Win10]

```py
import sys

from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableView
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt, QAbstractTableModel

class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        self._data = data

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            value = self._data[index.row()][index.column()]
            return value

    def rowCount(self, index):
        # The length of the outer list.
        return len(self._data)

    def columnCount(self, index):
        # The following takes the first sub-list, and returns
        # the length (only works if all rows are an equal length)
        return len(self._data[0])

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.table = QTableView()

        data = [[7,  9,  2],
                [1, -1, -1],
                [3,  5.3, -5],
                [3,  3,  2],
                [7,  8, 23],]

        self.model = TableModel(data)

        self.table.setModel(self.model)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "no lines"? (note: due to low reputation, it's expected that you don't put too many code lines in order to prevent questions that have mostly code, which is often the case for new users who don't know [ask] good questions yet)

Comment: On linux the row numbers have row lines, top and bottom.

Comment: Please try to be more clear, I'm on Linux and your code shows the expected behavior: the vertical header only shows the row number. Can you explain (possibly with a screenshot) what do you mean by "row numbers have row lines, top and bottom"?

Comment: https://imgur.com/H3bWZtK notice that the left vertical header the row numbers have lines above and below each number the win10 does not

Comment: @Fred try with: `app.setStyle("fusion")`

Comment: @Fred Ok, those are *section separators* ("row lines" is a bit ambiguous). As you can see from eyllanesc's comment, they depend on the current style. If you don't like having the fusion style set for the whole application, you could use `self.table.verticalHeader().setStyle(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.create('fusion'))`, otherwise you can override the drawing behavior, but you need to subclass QHeaderView and override its `paintSection()` by also calling the default base implementation, and then set it for the view with `setVerticalHeader()`.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  Did not know the correct term.